# dlookup formatting confusion

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am having some difficulty doing a simple dlookup. Usually I don't have any issues with them

**The code:**

```
ExploreMatch = DLookup("[ID]", "[tbl_Likes]", "[ID] =  '" & ExploreID1 & "'")
```

**The Problem:**
I think the problem is within my ID.

As an example my ID is a number, date and time all combined like this: **1234501/01/2018 13:00:25**

**Error:**
Data Type mismatch in expression

Anyone able to identify what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: what is the data type of `exploreID1` and `ExploreMatch` ?

Comment: the property for both texts boxes are blank - Assuming this defaults to text?

Comment: You can't assume that. Look at the definitions of the two and adjust them to match.

Comment: Are you sure the `ID` column is a string containing such data?  That seems like a really odd way to store data

Comment: Check the data type of the ID column in the tbl_Likes table. Tell us what this is, and we can advise you of a fix.

Answer (score 0):

You issue is that you mentioned that `[ID]` is a `Number` and you are trying to search for `"[ID] =  '" & ExploreID1 & "'"` to match a string.

You will never get a match because the data types are not the same.

If you want this to work and assuming that `ExploreID1` is indeed a number too then it should be written like this:

```
Dim ExploreMatch As Long 'can also be INT depending on length

ExploreMatch = DLookup("[ID]", "[tbl_Likes]", "[ID] = " & ExploreID1)
```

When you want to search with Number you cannot use single quotes around the search as this denotes a string.